# Difference while working with WMI via VBScript and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wmi

I have a test Windows XP SP3 clean install with power shell. It's a very strange difference if i access WMI from PowerShell and from VBScript. From powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject 'Win32_OperatingSystem" | select Caption
```

This correctly displays "Windows XP Professional". And same code written as VBScript:

```
WScript.Echo( GetObject( "winmgmts:Win32_OperatingSystem" ).Caption )
```

Displays "null" O_O. Why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the VBScript equivalent:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set objSet = wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each obj in objSet
    WScript.Echo obj.Caption
    Exit For
Next
```

**Although there is only one Operating System, a WMI query always returns a list.**

Ok, now, the difference - Using the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet, since there is only one operation system, you get the object directly rather than a list when you do `Get-WmiObject "Win32_OperatingSystem"` ( use GetType to see that this is actually of type `System.Management.ManagementObject` )

Since there will be multiple processes, `get-wmiobject win32_process` would give a array. ( use GetType to see that this is of type `System.Object[]`

The following would not give any output:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_process).Caption
```

Whereas the below would:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_process)[0].Caption
```